# Unable to download excel file from Angular 8 and server side code is .net core webapi 3.1

Tags: angular8, asp.net-core-webapi

sorry for duplicate issue but none of existed solutions haven't resolved my issue.

when trying to download excel file from Angular8,getting below error.

[image]

i'm implemented method which is return file by using .net core web api 3.1.below is the method which is return excel file.

```
 [Route("downloadClaims")]
    [HttpGet]
    public FileResult DownloadClaims(int userId)
    {
      var memory = new MemoryStream();
        using (var stream = new FileStream("E:/AddClaim.xlsx", FileMode.Open))
        {
            stream.CopyTo(memory);
        }
        memory.Position = 0;

        var mimeType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";

        return File(memory, mimeType, "AddClaim.xlsx");
    }
```

handling download functionality in Angular8. please find below code my angular service.

```
 downLoadAllClaims():Observable<Blob>
         {
        let httpOption = {
          headers: new HttpHeaders({
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'responseType': 'blob' as 'json',
            'Access-Control-Expose-Headers':'Content-Disposition'
            , 'observe': 'response'
          })
        }
          return this.http.get<Blob>(baseURL+'/downloadClaims',httpOption);
       }
```

and my component code is as below.

```
 downLoadClaim(_evnt):void{
this.claimService.downLoadAllClaims().subscribe(
  blob => {
    saveAs(blob,"AllClaims.xlsx")
  },
  error => {
    console.log("Something went wrong while downloading");
  });
```

}

file is not getting downloading.not understanding what did i miss?

Comment: when i enter web api download url in browser file is getting downloading successfully but in angular it's not getting download

Comment: solved this issue?